# SyntaxError: Unexpected token / ... Blueimp jQuery File Upload

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I set up this multiple file upload plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) on my local machine (mac osx default server). Everything is working perfectly, when I upload an image I get back this response

```
[{
"name":"subaru-wrx-poster-i3(1).jpg",      
"size":142583,"type":"image\/jpeg",
"url":"http:\/\/shipwatchpointe.dev\/bundles\/jupload\/uploads\/files\/52\/subaru-wrx-poster-i3%20%281%29.jpg",
"thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/shipwatchpointe.dev\/bundles\/jupload\/uploads\/thumbnails\/52\/subaru-wrx-poster-i3%20%281%29.jpg",
"delete_url":"http:\/\/shipwatchpointe.dev\/upload\/upload\/?file=subaru-wrx-poster-i3%20%281%29.jpg&_method=DELETE",
"delete_type":"POST"
}]
```

However,  I just pushed to a staging area on an EC2 instance and now I'm getting this response

```
//
```

With an error on the frontend that says...

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

I threw a bunch of dies everywhere I could think of but I'm not reaching them and still getting the same response. The EC2 instance is running Ubuntu 12.10 and I ensured that in /etc/mime.types that application/json json is there, but for some reason it looks like it is still trying to render it as html and throwing me that error. What could be the issue here on my staging server that's not present on my local server? I can paste my code, but there are a lot of snippets that I suspect may be causing the issue.

**Edit**
Here are the response headers on my local server (works fine)

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:1532
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Wed, 03 Apr 2013 18:13:47 GMT
ETag:"30d598-5fc-4d978d09b8a80"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Wed, 03 Apr 2013 18:13:46 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22      
   OpenSSL/0.9.8r
```

Here are the response headers on my staging server (not working)

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:23
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 03 Apr 2013 18:07:24 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
```

Comment: What is your maximum upload file size? Also, please can you show us the response headers that your browser gives you (it might help us along the way)?

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 20M upload_tmp_dir = /tmp file_uploads = On

Comment: I just also went through my entire php.ini's for both servers and there is nothing out of the ordinary that would cause the error, I would think. I changed upload max file size back to 2M after trying 20M and recommented the upload tmp directory..

Comment: Could it be because the uploaded image is given a content-type of text/html on the ubuntu server, while locally it gives a content-type of image/png?

Comment: It's possible, though I don't see how it could be given that type. At first I thought It was a Laravel/BlueImp compatibility issue, considering it uses `header()` and `echo ...` (which are not ever meant to be used), but then I doubted it because it works on your local server... So, I'm not quite sure what's going on here.

Comment: Could you perhaps also post any relevant error logs, if any? Apache errors, BlueImp logs, etc.

Comment: The apache error log is clean. I'm not sure if there is a blueimp error log anywhere.

Comment: I see that the content length differs from the length of the output you stated in your question. Is that really all of it? Could you check using a debug tool, or your browser's console?

Comment: turns out that I had a file called 'upload' with commented out code like so // <?php .. which was a previous attempt at uploading images. My request is setup like this /upload/upload .. and it was somehow hitting /upload not getting through and showing that error. Once I deleted that file, i had some gd library errors but that was simple and I just updated my server and it works! Can't believe something as simple as that got past me, I'm sorry to waste everyones time. @MikeAnthony you were the biggest help as I went through and started trouble shooting so if you answer I'll give you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an issue with reading files here. Check/Grep your staging server for any source files that have the double slash `//` in weird places (say the beginning of a PHP file).

It may be running into that file, erroneously printing those slashes, and ending output.

If this is the case, the BlueImp code is more than likely not being seen by the server, hence all those plain and simple output headers that have absolutely nothing to do with the upload.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup

> Using jQuery File Upload (UI version) on PHP websites The provided
>   example implementation works out of the box and only needs one step
>   for you to add it to your PHP based website:
>
> Download the plugin archive, extract it and upload the extracted
>   folder (you may rename it) to your server. Visit the uploaded
>   directory - you should see the same file upload interface as the demo,
>   allowing you to upload files to your website.
>
> If uploading files doesn't work, make sure that the php/files and
>   php/thumbnails directories permissions allow your server write access.

Are you sure you have the correct permissions for "php/files" and "php/thumbnails" ?

Those are really the only installation instructions I could find. Did you simply just copy the files to your server or are you using your own implementation? Sometimes it helps to start with the simplest example, then add your stuff afterwards to rule out some of the more obvious problems.

If you have changed the code, it will help to have a look at your changes, there might be something there that is causing the issue.

Comment: files and thumbnails are all 777...I'm using this plugin with Laravel. I think I'll make a gist of my code implementation

Answer (score 1):

Your content type looks different on local vs webserver. Looks like it may be an improperly configured web server.

Comment: I would think so too. @coryjacik, are there any other strange errors on your staging server? Does everything else work?

Answer (score 0):

Does your upload folder have write permission?

Comment: 777 is probably overkill but whatever